# viewWillAppear not invoked for subview controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have an odd case -- a view controller that creates its own view in `loadView` and which is then added to an existing view.

Here is the code that creates and adds the VC:

```
self.doneButtonViewController = [[DoneButtonViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:self.doneButtonViewController.view];
```

This code is executed in `viewDidLoad` of the "parent" VC.

The odd thing is that the `viewWillAppear` method of the added VC is never invoked (nor is `viewDidAppear`), but the `viewWillDisappear` method of the added VC *is* invoked (at the appropriate time), just as one would expect.

Any clue as to why `viewWillAppear` is not getting invoked?

Comment: (FWIW, this exercise is purely to obtain the viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear behavior of the subview, to implement a relatively "clean" DONE button for the numeric keypad.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The application isn't aware of the subview's view controller if you do this, you need to introduce view controller containment to make the root view controller aware. Doing so will handle any events like this.

Because `loadView` could be called more than once pre iOS 6, I'd advise creating the view controller within `init`, and then add the subview within `loadView`. It should be like this:

```
- (id)init {
    ...
    self.doneButtonViewController = [[DoneButtonViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.doneButtonViewController];
    [self.doneButtonViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    ...
}

- (void)loadView {
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:self.doneButtonViewController.view];
    ...
}
```

See "Implementing a Container View Controller" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Obviously the loadView implementation would need to construct the rest of the parent view controller's view as well, but this is the right answer. The code can be in viewDidLoad if you are using storyboards or xibs to make the parent VC.

Comment: Problem is, I'm trying to come up with a minimal scheme for adding this -- basically invoke one factory method that creates the VC and adds the view.

Comment: You'd have to pass in a reference to the view controller it's being added to, and use the same process. If you worry this may happen more than once, then either have checking code inside the factory to not add duplicates, or have `removeFromParentViewController:` at the ready  if you need to remove it.

Comment: I'd tried addChildViewController, but I didn't realize I needed addSubview as well.  With the pair it works more or less as expected.

Comment: All addChildViewController does is create a link between the two view **controllers**, it does nothing regarding the views themselves. This link allows events, such as viewWillAppear: to be propagated down to the child view controllers, so they in turn can manage their own view. The actual adding of the views themselves need to be added the traditional way as well.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, adding child view controller in parent view controller can solve the problem that "viewWillAppear" of the child view controller not get called.